# Why did we use case 0 and 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL query to find all the details of 1970 winners by the ordered to subject and winner name; but the list contain the subject Economics and Chemistry at last.

```
YEAR SUBJECT                   WINNER                                        COUNTRY                CATEGORY
---- ------------------------- --------------------------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
1970 Physics                   Hannes Alfven                                 Sweden                 Scientist
1970 Physics                   Louis Neel                                    France                 Scientist
1970 Chemistry                 Luis Federico Leloir                          France                 Scientist
1970 Physiology                Ulf von Euler                                 Sweden                 Scientist
1970 Physiology                Bernard Katz                                  Germany                Scientist
1970 Literature                Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn                        Russia                 Linguist
1970 Economics                 Paul Samuelson                                USA                    Economist
1970 Physiology                Julius Axelrod                                USA                    Scientist
1971 Physics                   Dennis Gabor                                  Hungary                Scientist
1971 Chemistry                 Gerhard Herzberg                              Germany                Scientist
1971 Peace                     Willy Brandt                                  Germany                Chancellor
1971 Literature                Pablo Neruda                                  Chile                  Linguist
1971 Economics                 Simon Kuznets                                 Russia                 Economist
1978 Peace                     Anwar al-Sadat                                Egypt                  President
1978 Peace                     Menachem Begin                                Israel                 Prime Minister
1987 Chemistry                 Donald J. Cram                                USA                    Scientist
1987 Chemistry                 Jean-Marie Lehn                               France                 Scientist
1987 Physiology                Susumu Tonegawa                               Japan                  Scientist
1994 Economics                 Reinhard Selten                               Germany                Economist
1994 Peace                     Yitzhak Rabin                                 Israel                 Prime Minister
1987 Physics                   Johannes Georg Bednorz                        Germany                Scientist
1987 Literature                Joseph Brodsky                                Russia                 Linguist
1987 Economics                 Robert Solow                                  USA                    Economist
1994 Literature                Kenzaburo Oe                                  Japan                  Linguist
```

answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE year=1970 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner;
```

Can someone explain the `case` and `order by` logic in that answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements say that Economics and Chemistry must be last. So we have to use `ORDER BY` to control the order of the results.

When `subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry')` is true, the `CASE` expression returns `1`. Otherwise it's `0`. Since `0` is lower than `1`, and we're ordering in ascending order, the rows where this is `0` will be put first.

Answer (score 3):

The `case` expression is returning 1 if the subject is one of the special subjects and 0 otherwise.  Because of the ascending sort, the 0s are before the 1s in the result set . So, Economics and Chemistry are after all the other subjects.

MySQL has a convenient shorthand for this, because booleans are treated as numbers in a numeric context.  So a shorter expression that does the same thing is:

```
ORDER BY ( subject IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') ) ASC,
         subject, winner
```